# User data validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jQuery AJAX and ASP.Net web methods. I need to check user data entered in to HTML controls, I know that there are a lot of jQuery plugins but I used them one by one, but no luck, the issue is they use `<form id="" action=""></form>` tag while I do not. Also I do not submit my form as it is a jQuery AJAX application. I want some fields to have only floating points and some not null. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblcontry" runat="server" Text="Select Country">   </asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <select id="cmbCountry">
                <option value="0">Select Country</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblCname" runat="server" Text="City Name"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtCityName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblDialCode" runat="server" Text="Dial Code"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtDialCode" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblKeywords" runat="server" Text="KeyWords"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><textarea id="txtKeywords" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="btnsave" value="Save" />
            <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnsave").click(function () {
        //here i want to check fields first and then save data.
        SaveData();
    });
}
```

I have imported all files and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#btnsave").click(function () {

      var isValid = false;      
      //manual validation examples, change to your needs
      if($('#'+ <%=txtCityName.ClientID %>).val() == '')
      {
          //tell the user
      }
      else
      {
          isValid = true; 
      }

      if(isNaN(parseFloat($('#'+ <%=txtDialCode.ClientID %>).val())))
      {
          //tell the user
      }
      else
      {
          isValid = true; 
      }         


      if (isValid) SaveData();
   });

}
```

Comment: `parseFloat` check won't fully work. If the value is for example `0hi` `parseFloat` will retrun `0` which is not `NaN`.

Comment: Like I said, it's an example of how to do the manual validation, change to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate if the input have a floating point value as:

```
var val = $("#idofelement").val()
if (parseFloat(val) != val) {
  // value is not a number
}
```

You can check if the input value is not null like this:

```
if ($("idofelement").val()) {
  // value is a empty string
}
```